# Binding Property not found for 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.Command'

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I'm pretty new to MAUI, and i'm working on a simple CRUD-App to get into it. Now I have all the functions implementet, but now when I linked the `AddUpdateObject()` function to the submit button, it says that this function doesn't exist

This is my XAML:

```
    <StackLayout Margin="10" Spacing="20">
        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="10">
           <Label Text="Name" FontSize="16"/>
           <Entry Text="{Binding Name}" Placeholder="Name"/>
           <BoxView HeightRequest="0.8" Color="Gray"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

        <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding AddUpdateObject}" />
     </StackLayout>
```

This is my Code-Behind:

```
using project.ViewModels;
namespace project.Views;

public partial class AddObjectAlbumDetail : ContentPage
{
    public AddUpdateAlbumDetail(AddUpdateObjectDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;    
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And this is my `AddUpdateObject()` function in `AddUpdateObjectDetailViewModel`:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private string _name;


[ICommand]
        public async void AddUpdateObject()
        {
            var response = await _objectService.AddObject(new Models.TestModel
            {
                Name = Name,
                //ReleaseDate=Date,
            }) ;

            if(response > 0)
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Created", "Object Created!", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Not Created", "Something went wrong while creating", "OK");

            }
        }
```

I'm sure the model is right since it only contains 1 attribute (string) and an auto incrementing id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Call InitializeComponent first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The [ICommand] is [RelayCommand] now.
2. The InitializeComponent is called first.
3. The command is bound by {Binding AddUpdateObjectCommand} not AddUpdateObject.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem was mainly the "AddUpdateObjectCommand", after I added this it worked :)

Comment: @IlianGionHäsler I know it is the "main" problem. It is not bad idea, to check 1 and 2 as well. It wont hurt to update your MVVM and get used to initialize before other code. It will save you from problems in the future.

Comment: Yes sure thank you, I will take a look at it. The project i'm working on is for school and will be graded soon, so there will be no "future" for this project. But this hint of yours will surely help me in the future, if I want to use .NET Maui